# Making use of an object's fields implicit in a block of code

Tags: rebol, rebol3

Let's say I have:

```
 foo: object [bar: 10]

 print foo/bar ;-- output 10
```

Is there some **xxx** for saying:

```
 foo: object [bar: 10]

 xxx foo [
     print bar ;-- output 10
 ]
```

Binding will work, but is ugly (puts object reference after the block) and you have to call DO:

```
 foo: object [bar: 10]

 do bind [
     print bar ;-- output 10
 ] foo
```

*(It also mutates the block parameter by default...which is probably not a good general property for the sought-after xxx.)*

USE would seem like a good word for xxx, but it is taken for something else already: it lets you declare words inside a local context while leaving the previous definitions of that word alone:

```
 foo: object [bar: 10]

 use [foo] [
     foo: object [bar: 20]
     print foo/bar ;-- prints 20
 ]

 print foo/bar ;-- prints 10
```

Does something already do what I want in the box, or does one have to write it?  WITH might be a good name, from other languages with a parallel kind of feature.

One option would be to make it an extension of use...perhaps what it did if you gave it a GET-WORD! in the list.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the primary use-cases for [`in`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/in.html), the "inverted" cousin of `bind`:

```
>> foo: object [bar: 10]
== make object! [
    bar: 10
]

>> do in foo [print bar]
10
```

If you don't want the code block mutated, add a `copy` to the mix: `do in foo copy [print bar]`.

Be sure to also check out (again) the the answer to "[How to use IN with a block instead of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059228/how-to-use-in-with-a-block-instead-of-an-object)".

Comment: Right... but you still need the do.  *(I actually added the "here's how you'd do it with bind after writing the rest of the question.)*  Wondering if there was any construct without a do.