# How are 'bind' and 'in' different?

Tags: rebol2

Take the following code which creates a *context*:

```
c: context [a: 2]
```

You can see it creates a context `c`, and that `a` is not bound in the *global context*:

```
>> ?? c
c: make object! [
    a: 2
]
>> a
** Script Error: a has no value
** Near: a
```

Now if you use `bind 'a c`, it returns the value of the word in the context it was bound:

```
>> get bind 'a c
== 2
```

Which is also the same as `in c 'a`:

```
>> (get bind 'a c) = (get in c 'a)
== true
```

Looks like `in` is a version of `bind` with flipped arguments

## So, *how is `in` different?*

There are some obvious feature additions in `bind`, like having a refinement `/copy` for efficiency, and also accepting a `block!` instead of a single word for its `words` argument.

In which case, the question becomes, why `in`?

#### Note

This was initially motivated by comments in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059228/how-to-use-in-with-a-block-instead-of-an-object/39812409), when I didn't quite understood what bind does, and a discussion on [gitter](https://gitter.im/red/help?at=58cf3733a84f611959c2043d) prompted me to post this

Answer (score 1):

The big difference is that BIND can propagate the context of a word:

```
>> q: func [/local a b][a: 1 b: 2 return 'a]
>> get bind 'b q
== 2
>> get in q 'b
** Script Error: in expected object argument of type: object port
** Near: get in q 'b
```

Rebol 2 only of course.